# How to set a Max width on my page containers

Tags: css, wordpress

Currently on our company website, there is no max width set. Therefore, no matter the size of the screen you're looking at it on, it will try and extend to that width. I would like to change that so it stops expanding at a certain max width -- say 1600 pixels wide.

I hope that someone can assist me with this code.

http://visualicreative.com/industries/non-profit/

Comment: Have you considered using CSS max-width property ? E.G. : max-width : 1600px; ?

Comment: I'm not even sure the OP even knows CSS...If so, I hope he includes some code in his post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try adding this line in responsive.css** (last line):

```
#page, #main { width: auto;  max-width: 1600px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

*It will basically set a max-width and center the #main and #page element.*

Seeing the code on your website, I'm not sure that will set a max-width to all your website. **It's a really choatic piece of code**.